# How to register an InstanceCreator with Gson in Kotlin?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson

I can use Code 1 to save `MutableList<MDetail>` to json string using Gson correctly,
But I get the error when I try to restore `MutableList<MDetail>` object from json string with Code 2.
I have search some resources, it seems that I need to register an InstanceCreator.

How can I write a register an `InstanceCreator` code with Kotlin? Thanks!

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface model.DeviceDef. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

**Code 1**

```
private var listofMDetail: MutableList<MDetail>?=null
mJson = Gson().toJson(listofMDetail) //Save
```

**Code 2**

```
var mJson: String by PreferenceTool(this, getString(R.string.SavedJsonName) , "")
var aMListDetail= Gson().fromJson<MutableList<MDetail>>(mJson)

inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJson(json: String) = this.fromJson<T>(json, object: TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
```

**My Class**

```
interface DeviceDef

data class BluetoothDef(val status:Boolean=false):  DeviceDef
data class WiFiDef(val name:String, val status:Boolean=false) : DeviceDef

data class MDetail(val _id: Long, val deviceList: MutableList<DeviceDef>)
{
    inline fun <reified T> getDevice(): T {
        return deviceList.filterIsInstance(T::class.java).first()
    }
}
```

**Added**

After I use `val myGson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().registerTypeAdapterFactory(adapter).create()`, I can get the correct result when I use `open class DeviceDef` , why?

```
open class DeviceDef

data class BluetoothDef(val status:Boolean=false):  DeviceDef()
data class WiFiDef(val name:String, val status:Boolean=false) : DeviceDef()

val adapter = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
        .of(DeviceDef::class.java)
        .registerSubtype(BluetoothDef::class.java)
        .registerSubtype(WiFiDef::class.java)


data class MDetail(val _id: Long, val deviceList: MutableList<DeviceDef>)
{
    inline fun <reified T> getDevice(): T {
        return deviceList.filterIsInstance(T::class.java).first()
    }
}

val myGson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().registerTypeAdapterFactory(adapter).create()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson deserializing nested objects with InstanceCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567719/gson-deserializing-nested-objects-with-instancecreator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gson is having a hard time deserialising polymorphic objects as in your `MutableList<DeviceDef>`. Here's what you need to do:

1. Add the [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) to your project manually (does not seem to be [part of gson library](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1104)). See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22081826/8073652).
2. Change your code to use the factory

   Create `Gson` instance:

   ```
   val adapter = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
           .of(DeviceDef::class.java)
           .registerSubtype(BluetoothDef::class.java)
           .registerSubtype(WiFiDef::class.java)

   val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().registerTypeAdapterFactory(adapter).create()
   ```
3. register each of your subtypes in the factory and it will work as intended :)

Comment: Thanks! your code works well. And more, would you please see the Added section in the question?   After I use `val myGson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().registerTypeAdapterFactory(adapter).create()`, I can get the correct result when I use `open class DeviceDef` , why?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have 'by lazy' initializing parameter or value in your data class
[more information](https://hanru-yeh.medium.com/deserialize-classes-with-fields-by-delegate-crashes-when-using-gson-7c31fb5a792d)