# Kotlin: Reified type parameter makes Gson fail

Tags: java, kotlin, gson

I've encountered a weird behavior using Gson deserializing within a function with `reified` type. It only happens when `interfaces` are involved in the type parameter.

Take the following code:

```
val toBeSerialized = listOf("1337")
with(Gson()) {
    val ser = toJson(toBeSerialized)
    val deser = fromJson<List<Serializable>>(ser)
}
```

Line number 4 makes use of a custom extension function `Gson.fromJson(json: String): T`.

It **fails** if `T` is defined as reified:

```
inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJson(json: String): T = fromJson<T>(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
```

And it **works** if it is defined as a normal type parameter:

```
fun <T> Gson.fromJson(json: String): T = fromJson<T>(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
```

(Note that making `T` reified makes no sense here, just want to understand its impact in the special use case)

The exception when using `reified` looks as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for ? extends java.io.Serializable. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:210)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
    at SoTestsKt.main(SoTests.kt:25)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Interface can't be instantiated! Interface name: java.io.Serializable
    at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator.assertInstantiable(UnsafeAllocator.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$1.newInstance(UnsafeAllocator.java:49)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:223)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: It's not actually using the type you pass it, this example is just getting lucky with Gson's defaults. Try it with: `val deser = Gson().fromJson<LinkedList<Serializable>>(ser);` for instance

Comment: Isn't it the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050487/how-to-register-an-instancecreator-with-gson-in-kotlin

Comment: Not at all. But this questions made me notice the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version that uses `reified T` fails because it's trying to de-serialize "1337" as a `Serializable`, which is an interface, so it can not be instantiated, and by default there is no type adapter which can de-serialize into a `Serializable` (like there is for `List<...>`). The easiest way to fix this is to pass `List<String>` as a type argument.

In the non-reified version there is no actual type information being passed to your extension function. You can verify this by printing the type you get from the token:

```
fun <T> Gson.fromJson(json: String): T {
    val tt = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type;
    println(tt);
    return fromJson(json, tt);
}
```

In the none reified version that will just print `T` (i.e. no actual type information is available), but in the `reified` version it will print the actual type (+ any Kotlin declaration site variance modifiers, so `List<String>` becomes `List<? extends String>`). (I don't know why Gson silently ignores this error of missing type information).

The reason the non `reified` version works is a coincidence. Since Gson's default type for de-serializing `["1337"]` is `ArrayList<String>` and that is also what you get. It just happens to be assignable to a `List`, and since generics are erased there is no class cast exception for the mismatch between `String` and `Serializable` as the type argument. It works out in the end any ways since `String` implements `Serializable`.

If you slightly modify the example, where a different cast happens, for instance by specifying a different kind of `List`, you run into trouble:

```
val deser = fromJson<LinkedList<Serializable>>(ser)
```

Throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList`

You need `reified T` to be able to pass on the type information, but it also means that a failure will happen earlier, and does not go unnoticed due to type erasure, like in the non-`reified` version.

Answer (score 1):

As what @Jorn Vernee mentioned, `reified` is needed for serializing/deserializing the json. If `reified` is not added, it will be treated as `List<Object>` and the final deserialized object will have type `List<LinkedTreeMap>` and you will get [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444863/google-gson-linkedtreemap-class-cast-to-myclass/32494079) when you try to use those object as your interface.

To serialize/deserialize interface, you need to register a custom adapter to add the type information of the implemented class. Here is a adapter class where I reference from this [site](http://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html) and make some changes on it.

```
class InterfaceAdapter<T : Serializable> : JsonSerializer<T>, JsonDeserializer<T> {

    companion object {
        private val CLASSNAME = "CLASSNAME"
        private val DATA = "DATA"
    }

    @Throws(JsonParseException::class)
    override fun deserialize(jsonElement: JsonElement, type: Type, jsonDeserializationContext: JsonDeserializationContext): T {
        val jsonObject = jsonElement.asJsonObject
        val prim = jsonObject.get(CLASSNAME) as JsonPrimitive
        val className = prim.asString
        val klass = getObjectClass(className)
        return jsonDeserializationContext.deserialize(jsonObject.get(DATA), klass)
    }

    override fun serialize(jsonElement: T, type: Type, jsonSerializationContext: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement {
        val jsonObject = JsonObject()
        jsonObject.addProperty(CLASSNAME, jsonElement.javaClass.name)
        jsonObject.add(DATA, jsonSerializationContext.serialize(jsonElement))
        return jsonObject
    }

    private fun getObjectClass(className: String): Class<*> {
        try {
            return Class.forName(className)
        } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
            throw JsonParseException(e.message)
        }
    }
}
```

Register the adapter to the gson object and also provide the type information.

```
inline fun <reified T> Any.toJson(): String {
    val builder = GsonBuilder()
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Serializable::class.java, InterfaceAdapter<Serializable>())
    val gson = builder.create()
    return gson.toJson(this, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
}

inline fun <reified T> fromJson(json: String): T {
    val builder = GsonBuilder()
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Serializable::class.java, InterfaceAdapter<Serializable>())
    val gson = builder.create()
    return gson.fromJson<T>(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
}
```

Example code:

```
data class User(val name: String) : Serializable

val data = listOf(User("Sam"))
val ser = data.toJson<List<Serializable>>()
val deser = fromJson<List<Serializable>>(ser)

println(ser)
println(deser.get(0)::class)
println(deser.get(0))

/* Output
    [{"CLASSNAME":"User","DATA":{"name":"Sam"}}]
    class User
    User(name=Sam)
*/
```