# Why does the expert change MutableList to List?

Tags: kotlin

I asked a question at [How to design a complex class which incude some classes to make expansion easily in future in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586213/how-to-design-a-complex-class-which-incude-some-classes-to-make-expansion-easily) about how to design a complex class which incude some classes to make expansion easily in future in Kotlin.

A expert named s1m0nw1 give me a great answer as the following code.

But I don't know why he want to change `MutableList` to `List` at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47960036/revisions , I can get the correct result when I use MutableList. Could you tell me?

**The code**

```
interface DeviceDef
data class BluetoothDef(val Status: Boolean = false) : DeviceDef
data class WiFiDef(val Name: String, val Status: Boolean = false) : DeviceDef
data class ScreenDef(val Name: String, val size: Long) : DeviceDef 


class MDetail(val _id: Long, val devices: List<DeviceDef>) {

    inline fun <reified T> getDevice(): T {
        return devices.filterIsInstance(T::class.java).first()
    }
}
```

**Added**

I think that `mutableListOf<DeviceDef>` is better than `ListOf<DeviceDef>` in order to extend in future.

I can use `aMutableList.add()` function to extend  when I append new element of  `mutableListOf<DeviceDef>`.

If I use `ListOf<DeviceDef>`, I have to construct it with `listOf(mBluetoothDef1, mWiFiDef1, //mOther)`, it's not good. Right?

```
var aMutableList= mutableListOf<DeviceDef>()

var mBluetoothDef1= BluetoothDef(true)
var mWiFiDef1= WiFiHelper(this).getWiFiDefFromSystem()

aMutableList.add(mBluetoothDef1)
aMutableList.add(mWiFiDef1)

// aMutableList.add(mOther)  //This is extension

var aMDetail1= MDetail(myID, aMutableList)
```

Comment: you can find lots of answers just google "why immutable"

Comment: Imagine you're an artist doing paintings and sculptures. A museum asks you to borrow some of your artwork for an exhibition, open to anyone. Wouldn't you like it better if the museum told you "people in the museum may look, but they may not touch"? Same here: Since the class is supposed to only get data from the list and not modify it in any way, you'd better make that clear by accepting a List rather than a MutableList. It also allows passing more kinds of Lists, BTW, since all lists are not mutable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry for not giving an explanation in the first place. The differences are explained in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html).:

> Unlike many languages, Kotlin distinguishes between **mutable** and **immutable** collections (lists, sets, maps, etc). *Precise control over exactly when collections can be edited is useful for eliminating bugs, and for designing good APIs.*
>
> It is important to understand up front the difference between a read-only view of a mutable collection, and an actually immutable collection. Both are easy to create, but the type system doesn't express the difference, so keeping track of that (if it's relevant) is up to you.
>
> The Kotlin `List<out T>` type is an interface that provides **read-only** operations like size, get and so on. Like in Java, it inherits from `Collection<T>` and that in turn inherits from `Iterable<T>`. Methods that change the list are added by the `MutableList<T>` interface. [...]

The `List` interface provides a read-only view so that you cannot e.g add new elements to the list which has many advantages for instance in multithreaded environments. There may be situations in which you will use `MutableList` instead.

I also recommend the following discussion:
[Kotlin and Immutable Collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33727657/8073652)

**EDIT** (added content):

You can do this is a one-liner without any `add` invocation:

```
val list = listOf(mBluetoothDef1, mWiFiDef1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you please have a look at my Added content in the question?

Comment: See Edit in answer